# Building from source whilst already having a version installed

Tags: neovim, make

Using arm [on raspberry pi], I built Neovim  from source successfully, and I can run the bin from neovim/build/bin, which runs fine.

Initially I installed Neovim using apt. The repo for this distro has nvim 4.4.0 ...

I don't want to have Neovim4.4, and can easily apt remove it, but I wonder if there's anything I should to besides then copying my built bin to ... maybe /usr/bin/ ?
any libs?

What should I do to complete the build properly now?

Comment: There is probably a make install target or similar? In particular it should take care of binaries, libs, and runtime files.